# Cannot open GUI apps with sudo (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: display, sudo, root, gui, 17.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 and every time I try to open a graphical app as root (with sudo) these are the error messages that come out.
I have already tried `xhost +chips` (my username) and `xhost +root` but this is the error message that I get: `xhost: bad hostname "root"`.

```
chips@DELL:~$ sudo nautilus
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:2254): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

chips@DELL:~$ sudo wireshark 
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyQXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted

chips@DELL:~$ sudo rhythmbox
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display: 
Run 'rhythmbox --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

Comment: It does not seem to be the same problem, sorry

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10 as is so yes I am using Wayland

Comment: Have you tried `nautilus admin:///` (to access `/`), in general `nautilus admin://<path-to-directory>`?

Comment: Yes, `nautilus admin:///` asks for my password and then it starts, but I need it to be working with sudo

Comment: This trick is from one of the answers of the proposed duplicate. I would suggest you to go through all the answers. "*It does seem to be the same problem, sorry*"